# React: Persistent Storage Options?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have been reading about React and Redux lately. It looks very interesting and I'd like to use it for small personal projects. One question I keep coming back to is, when does data get saved to the database (or some sort of persistent storage)?

Most tutorials explain components, props, state but they I've not found a lot of solid information about saving said state to persistent storage. Some articles mention local storage but what happens when that is cleared? All the user's data is gone . . . ?

Eventually, a database has to be used at sometime, right?

I have been looking into [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to help with the API backend. Is this a good option? Is there someway to save to local storage instead so the user sees the UI update instantly and silently call an API endpoint after the fact?

Open to ideas and suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: This is a really broad question for SO. But yes, at some point you will need some persistent storage. Typically at server-side. In many tutorials you will find how to use WebAPIs to get + send data to server, and how to use async (ajax) calls for this. The code at the other end is typically where your database would reside. And yes, you could also do optimistic updates to also (not instead) store locally, while request to update database is running in background. I have no opinion on Axios (SO is probably not best place to ask this)

Answer (score 2):

This really is a broad topic but you're right that the internet is lacking in examples of data persistence. One reason is that neither react nor redux are frameworks that help with these; meaning it's a great application of the libraries but are not core to the abstract ideas they present.

That's not to say it's undoable, quite the opposite. With the help of redux middleware this becomes a fun task that works flawlessly with the rest of your application. There are many different ways of implementing data persistence so I'll just explain one here, which I use in my own apps.

**CouchDB + PouchDB + middleware**

- *CouchDB*: simple document storage in JSON format
- *PouchDB*: syncs your localStorage with a CouchDB instance to automagically allow offline use

Since databases introduce stateful behavior, redux suggests using middleware to not muck up your store with state kept outside itself. In this middleware you would sync up your DB instance to the store. This middleware simply reads the data in the DB and fires actions to insert it into the store. Your application then fires actions that the middleware picks up and uses to store data in its DB. Finally, the DB updates the store with the new data it inserted/updated/deleted.

It's a simple yet powerful way to persist JSON serializable data to a DB while maintaining a redux store.

Answer (score 0):

Use react-persistent-store-manager. Uses pull state and localforage for persistent data. It's quite straight forward.